# How to implement cookie in android application

Tags: android, cookies

I want to make a login application in Android.

Requirement of the project is to store user name and password for two days using cookie.

Is it possible to use cookies? If yes, then how? Can you give me the code?

Note: I can't use web view.

Comment: You should never store passwords in cookies.

Comment: in your question, its server cookie the problem, not android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a commenter already said, you aren't supposed to store password (even in encrypted form) in a cookie. What you can store is a session id. When user logs in the application, the application generates a session id for him/her, which will stay valid for two days. In every request that you make to the application, you add the session id as an HTTP header.

You can store the session id and the datetime it was issued in the preferences. When the user needs to make a new request to the application and the session hasn't expired, you can read the stored value.

Comment: Hi, i want to implement this in my project. But i am confused how to do that? will you send me some code to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looking to integrate this into the browser, then have a go at this.

If you look at the HTTP protocol, you can see that cookies are sent by the client in plain text in the request. This means you should have your application deliver them every time your request a page. This is not valid for local-only cookies, but I don't think that you're interested in these. If you want to set cookies from the server side, you will have to adapt your application to parse the response and look for cookies. (also HTTP protocol)

For a better view of the raw data you need to send or receive, you can monitor your traffic using Wireshark or a similar tool and see how the request/response look like.

I am currently working on a web-service that I need to implement on iPhone and this is my first idea of doing it. I haven't got to implement this yet (my web service is still not done) so there's not much more I can tell you at the moment.

[Edit:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
A useful page about this might be the Wikipedia HTTP Cookie page located here.

Comment: I know this post is far old but I've never heard about `local-only cookies` before, can you provide me more information? Maybe I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 1):

As Reno said, try to avoid storing the password in the cookie. Instead you should let the server generate a sessionID when logged in and let this ID expire on the Server after two days. SO you can login with the username and the sessionID you generated with logging in once.

I you want, you can store that sessionID in the cookie.