# How to auto login when I run the Android Application

Tags: android

Assume that I have login to system using PHP + MySQL, then, after I exit the apps, I run the apps again, no need to login again and auto login, Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: You are looking for cookie-like behaviour, see the following link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297925/how-to-implement-cookie-in-android-application

Comment: you can store username/password in SharredPreference/sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while first time login u get something username or userid in respones than store ther username or userid in sharedpreference like as shown below

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);

  prefs.edit().putInt("userid",userid).commit();
```

as after succesfull login this will store your userid in preference and u can check u are already login or not as

```
int Userid;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
Userid= mPrefs.getInt("userid", 0);  which will return defalut value 0 if u are not login
```

after check

```
 if(Userid>0){
  // Means  u are already logged in  do here code what u want if u are login 
  }else{
    // Means  u are not logged in than go to your login pageview from here
 }
```

this is just simple way for doing what u want suppose if u want logoout functionality on button click than onclick event u have to add following code for logout which will clear prefernce

```
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyAccountActivity.this);
 prefs.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: but how can it auto login when run the application again?

Comment: u have to get preference value and after check if condition first in which if u are not login than userid=0 according to my code as prefence default value and ur if condition goes into else portion and after login u have to store ur value as code shown as an above putint and it will put userid and next time if u came to that view or app u have userid than it go in if condition

Comment: you mean do not save any password in preference?

Comment: yes no need to store password

Comment: is it safe to do so ?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you should to do for Auto login:

1.Obtain a session id from login user web service.This session id is associated with every web service call you make.

2.Just store the session id in SharedPreferences or other form of persistent storage.When the app is restarted check whether the session id is defined or not.Make sure that on every log out you initialize it to null.If the session id in SharedPreferences is defined log the user in automatically.

3.Use this session id to make any further web service calls you make.